# Mule 1.3 config files having 'mule-descriptor' directly below 'mule-configuration' fails validation

Tags: xml, configuration, dtd, mule

I've been put on a project using a ancient mule version 1.3. They use a split configuration setup, as suggested e.g. [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/mule/mule/1.3.2/mule-1.3.2-website-docs.distribution-zip!/MULE/Using%20Multiple%20Configuration%20Files.html).

All these files had http://www.symphonysoft.com/dtds/mule/mule-configuration.dtd as their DTD definition. This turned out to be a problem for the just-as-old Mule IDE, since it apparently tries to load that URL, whose domain is gone.

I found a file at http://www.mulesoft.org/dtds/mule-configuration.dtd which would seem to be the same DTD. However, I have now gotten validation errors in all config files but the main mule-config.xml, since they follow the suggestion in the first link: Have mule-descriptor elements directly below the mule-configuration element. However, the DTD doesn't seem to allow this (the mule-descriptor element is below the model element):

```
<!ELEMENT mule-configuration (description?, environment-properties?,
  mule-environment-properties?, container-context*, security-manager?,
  transaction-manager?, agents?, connector*, endpoint-identifiers?,
  transformers?, global-endpoints?, interceptor-stack*, model*)>
```

Any ideas besides hosting a modified DTD ourselves? Are there another DTD available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just if anyone else get this problem: The 's' in "dtds" of the URL should have been a give-away: http://www.mulesoft.org/dtds/

The [1.3.3 DTD](http://www.mulesoft.org/dtds/mule-1.3.3-configuration.dtd) had the expected 'mule-descriptor' directly below 'mule-configuration', and both the Mule IDE and the Eclipse validation are now happy.

(The reason for the validation errors was that when I put a DTD there that could be loaded, Eclipse started to started to validate the XMLs. Another solution to this problem was to add an entry in the "XML Catalog" of Eclipse, which states that "if you find this PUBLIC id, then use this local file", at Preferences -> XML -> XML Catalog.)